# How do I fix the Rust error "linker 'cc' not found" for Debian on Windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows, rust

I'm running Debian on Windows 10 (Windows Subsystem for Linux) and installed Rust using the command:

```sh
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

There were no errors in the install, but when I tried to compile with `rustc` I got the error `linker 'cc' not found`.

Answer (score 401):

The Linux Rust installer doesn't check for a compiler toolchain, but seems to assume that you've already got a C linker installed! The best solution is to install the tried-and-true gcc toolchain.

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

If you need to target another architecture, install the appropriate toolchain and target the compilation as follows:

```
rustc --target=my_target_architecture -C linker=target_toolchain_linker my_rustfile.rs
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked for me.  I had installed the Microsoft C++ tools as suggested, but that didn't work.  I realized it was probably because I am running rustc in Ubuntu on Windows.

Comment: Same here. I was running it on WSL.

Comment: I had to install cmake on Ubuntu 20.04 WSL
`sudo apt install cmake`

Comment: You can configure the linker when choosing the target by adding this to a .config (in repo or workspace): e.g.: `[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu]
linker = "aarch64-linux-gcc"`

Comment: Why do you need a C linker?

Comment: This solved it for me as well. Running wsl2 Ubuntu.

Comment: I had to run also `sudo apt install pkg-config` in order to solve the issue completely on WSL Ubuntu. Fortunately, cargo was very informative, and I was able to solve it quickly :)

Comment: None of these suggestions have worked for me. Windows 11, WSL Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 67):

I ran the following 2 commands and it worked.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Comment: Simple and clear. Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 60):

You have to install some dependencies

for Arch Linux: `sudo pacman -S base-devel`

for Ubuntu: `sudo apt install build-essential`

for Centos: `sudo yum install gcc`

for Solus: `sudo eopkg it -c system.devel`

Comment: Question is regarding Windows Subsystem for Linux

Comment: Answer may be, too, since WSL allows different Linux distribution to be installed.

Answer (score 26):

Solution for CentOS:

```
yum -y install gcc
```

Answer (score 13):

if u are on wsl2 - ubuntu try to update the pacakges with following cmds:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Answer (score 5):

You can fix this problem by adding build essential package in linux

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution for Solus:

```
sudo eopkg it -c system.devel
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems Rust assumes you already have a C compiler.
For Fedora:

```
sudo dnf install gcc
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do an "Update and Upgrade" before installing setup tools.

Answer (score 0):

IF ABOVE IS NOT WORKING: cc is included in the "GCC" package. You need to uninstall GCC and then reinstall it if you have accidentally replaced or removed the cc binary.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt install build-essential cmake
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: ... why is CMake needed here? especially given that this is a _rust_ question?