# linker `cc` not found,

Tags: ubuntu, rust

After installing First time rust on ubuntu try to run this program.

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

**Error:**

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling test1 v0.1.0 (/home/saad/Documents/Rust/test1)
error: linker `cc` not found
  |
  = note: No such file or directory (os error 2)

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `test1`.
```

Comment: How did you install Rust? If you installed it with rustup, don't forget to install `build-essential`: `# apt install build-essential`

Comment: "sudo apt-get install update"

"sudo apt-get install crul"   I use these commands, then I use this command    "curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh"  And Installation starts.

Comment: Well, so as I said, you must install the `build-essential` package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the Rust error "linker 'cc' not found" for Debian on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52445961/how-do-i-fix-the-rust-error-linker-cc-not-found-for-debian-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As mentioned in the message, the linker 'cc' is missing.
You can install it using `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

After the installation completes, the problem should be solved.

Comment: For WSL installations please follow the accepted answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62215963/how-to-install-gcc-and-gdb-for-wslwindows-subsytem-for-linux)

Comment: What if you get this on a Windows machine (not WSL)? I'm seeing this on GitHub Actions? Surely there's a way to cross-compile, no?

Answer (score 9):

Your system is missing a C linker, which Rustup assumes that you already have. You can install one (among other potentially useful tools, like make) via the following command:

`sudo apt install build-essential`

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios That is very much true. My apologies, I'm not very well-versed in how cases like these usually are handled on Stackexchange. Would it be better to not answer the question in the case that there is a linked duplicate (which this question doesn't seem to be flagged as any more?)?

Answer (score 3):

This error happens mostly either linux or wsl.
You can fix it by running the following command :

```sh
sudo apt install build-essential
```

If still issue persists, please go on to install `gcc` as below

```sh
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

If `gcc` ended with some error, please go on with the following command also (This is purely optional only)

```sh
apt-get update --fix-missing
```