# How to install GCC and GDB for WSL(windows subsytem for linux)?

Tags: windows, gcc, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need gcc to compile a c code and unable to install gcc on wsl. I tried `sudo apt-get install gcc` but it doesn't work. This is the error.

```
hack@DESKTOP-VMQA3JB:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc : Depends: gcc-9 (>= 9.2.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't know the dependencies to install. Please help me with gdb also. thankyou.

Comment: Do you still have the problem after running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` ?

Comment: yeah it worked after update and upgrade.. Thank you !

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to:

1. Update and upgrade:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

[image]

2.Clean unrequired packages:

```sh
$ sudo apt autoremove -y
```

[image]

3. Install GCC:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install gcc -y
```

[image]

4. Check and confirmed installed gcc version:

```sh
gcc --version
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, just wanted to know what does "-y" in "sudo apt-get upgrade -y" mean?

Comment: @Parting it mean answer y (yes) fir any question to come and need confirmation ti proceed.