# Cargo build results in dependency compile error

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm having issues buidling projects with rust, my lib.rs only has this

```
use near_sdk::borsh::{self, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use near_sdk::{env, near_bindgen};

near_sdk::setup_alloc!();

#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(Default, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct Counter {
    // See more data types at https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html
    val: i8, // i8 is signed. unsigned integers are also available: u8, u16, u32, u64, u128
}

#[near_bindgen]
impl Counter {
  
    pub fn get_num(&self) -> i8 {
        return self.val;
    }

        self.val += 1;
        let log_message = format!("Increased number to {}", self.val);
        env::log(log_message.as_bytes());
        after_counter_change();
    }

 
    pub fn decrement(&mut self) {
       
        self.val -= 1;
        let log_message = format!("Decreased number to {}", self.val);
        env::log(log_message.as_bytes());
        after_counter_change();
    }
    pub fn reset(&mut self) {
        self.val = 0;
        // Another way to log is to cast a string into bytes, hence "b" below:
        env::log(b"Reset counter to zero");
    }
}

fn after_counter_change() {
    // show helpful warning that i8 (8-bit signed integer) will overflow above 127 or below -128
    env::log("Make sure you don't overflow, my friend.".as_bytes());
}
```

when i run RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --release  i get this error:

> error: linker `cc` not found   |   = note: No such file or directory
> (os error 2)
>
> error: could not compile `proc-macro2` due to previous error

if i add proc-macro2 to the dependecy, the error changes to cannot compile ...'other dependency' and it keeps adding new ones as i try to solve it adding them to Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "contract"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Near Inc <hello@nearprotocol.com>"]
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]

[dependencies]
near-sdk = "=4.0.0-pre.4"

[profile.release]
codegen-units=1
opt-level = "z"
lto = true
debug = false
panic = "abort"
overflow-checks = true
```

any help?

Answer (score 3):

No, you just need to install:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

EDIT (Adding more info):

> The Linux Rust installer doesn't check for a compiler toolchain, but seems to assume that you've already got a C linker installed! The best solution is to install the tried-and-true gcc toolchain.

[How do I fix the Rust error "linker 'cc' not found" for Debian on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52445961/how-do-i-fix-the-rust-error-linker-cc-not-found-for-debian-on-windows-10)

Credits to: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4498831/boiethios

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please explain why this solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

it was something wrong with my WSL ubuntu, my cargo version was different from the windows one, was able to build it with windows

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).